# Python NameError: name 'north' is not defined for Text Game

Tags: python, defined

I made this code for my text based game and i am receiving an error saying

```
 line 1, in <module>
userInput = input("Please enter a direction in which to travel: ")
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'north' is not defined
```

Here is my code

```
userInput = input("Please enter a direction in which to travel: ")
Map = {
    'north':'that way leads to the kitchen', 
    'south':'that way leads to the dining room', 
    'east':'that way leads to the entry', 
    'west':'that way leads to the living room'
}
if userInput == north:
    print Map['north']
elif userInput == south:
    print Map['south']
elif userInput == east:
    print Map['east']
elif userInput == West:
    print Map['west']
elif userInput == '':
    print "Please specify a various direction."
else:
    quit
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: If that's actually your code, you're liable to receive a lot of `IndentationErrors` after you put some quotes around your directions to make them strings.

Comment: The problem is with your if statement but you can also simplify greatly. Check my answer below. I have provided working code.

Comment: Also, there is no `quit` keyword in python.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
if userInput == north:
    ...
```

is asking whether the variable named `userInput` is the same as the variable `north`.

But you have not defined a variable named `north`. The line should be comparing to the string `'north'` like this.

```
if userInput == 'north':
    ...
```

However, you could test for the user input in your dictionary keys like this. I have changed your constant to all caps.

```
MAP = {
    'north':'that way leads to the kitchen', 
    'south':'that way leads to the dining room', 
    'east':'that way leads to the entry', 
    'west':'that way leads to the living room'
}
userInput = raw_input("Please enter a direction in which to travel: ")
if userInput in MAP.keys():
    print MAP[userInput]
```

Also, as mentioned in another answer, raw_input is safer than input.

An alternative is to catch the KeyError like this.

```
MAP = {
    'north':'that way leads to the kitchen', 
    'south':'that way leads to the dining room', 
    'east':'that way leads to the entry', 
    'west':'that way leads to the living room'
}
userInput = raw_input("Please enter a direction in which to travel: ")
try:
    print MAP[userInput]
except KeyError:
    print 'What?'
```

or repeat until valid input is provided like this (and make it case insensitive):

```
MAP = {
    'north':'that way leads to the kitchen', 
    'south':'that way leads to the dining room', 
    'east':'that way leads to the entry', 
    'west':'that way leads to the living room'
}
while True:
    userInput = raw_input("Please enter a direction in which to travel: ").lower()
    try:
        print MAP[userInput]
        break
    except KeyError:
        print '%s is not an option' % userInput
```

Comment: I am not sure why I got a down vote. Can anyone give me a clue (or an up vote)?

Answer (score 0):

When using Python 2, you should always be using [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) to get input from the user.

`input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`; thus your code is trying to find a variable called "north" when you type it in.

However, in Python 3, `input()` acts the same as `raw_input()` did in Python 2.

---

You also should be comparing your input to strings, and not variables you have created. For example, `if userInput == north` should be `if userInput == 'north'`. This makes `'north'` a string.

You can just sum up your code with:

```
print Map.get(userInput, 'Please specify a various direction')
```

Comment: Oh okay, so change userInput = input("Please enter a direction in which to travel: ")  to userInput = raw_input("Please enter a direction in which to travel: ")

Comment: Valid comment, but this does not fix the bug.

Comment: @GraemeStuart How is it now :3

Comment: @Haidro, Yes, that's good. Except the control flow will merge so it can't be built into a bigger programme. Better to catch the error or test as in my answer.